# python 2.7 code in python 3

Tags: python

Facing this issue while I am trying to use 2.7 code in python 3:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-1eee8eed88cf> in <module>()
     15                 signature = hashlib.md5(concatenation.encode("utf-8")).digest()
     16                 #row[BVUSERTOKENCOLUMN] = binascii.hexlify(signature + valuestring)
---> 17                 hashval = binascii.hexlify(signature + valuestring)
     18                 #print hashval
     19                 spamwriter.writerow([userid, date, maxage, hashval])

TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Thank you Prune :)

Comment: Thanks Prune! Sorry guys I will try to be more explanatory from next time. Thanks for understanding as first timer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no background, from what I infer, the problem is just that signature and valuestring are different types here. Maybe you can do either of the below?

```
hashval = binascii.hexlify(signature + valuestring.encode('utf-8'))
```

or

```
hashval = binascii.hexlify(signature + bytes(valuestring, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: Don't add a comment about your correction. *Edit your answer* (which I have done for you).

Comment: Thansk Wang Rex, I think it worked but I will move forward with further code to see if it does complete the whole function.